# Python widget for real time plotting

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter, wxpython

Is there a minimalistic python module out there that I can use to plot real time data that comes in  every 2-3 seconds?

I've tried matplotlib but I'm having a couple errors trying to get it to run so I'm not looking for something as robust and with many features.

Comment: matplotlib should be fine with 2-3 seconds updates. you may want to try [this demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/wire3d_animation_demo.html) to see the frame per second rate

Comment: problem is with matpotlib none of the examples work. The python icon pops on my dock on macosx but the gui isn't there.

Comment: what are you using for the gui widgets?

Comment: It should be generated right? Anyways I decided to go ahead with pylab because I found some examples that actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter, which is part of python, comes with a canvas widget that can be used for some simple plotting. It can draw lines and curves, and one datapoint every couple of seconds is very easy for it to handle.